# Methods for avoiding division by zero in numerical approximations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a simple function in python which numerically approximates a definite integral using the trapezoidal rule. Unfortunately, errors can arise with asymptotic functions caused by zero division e.g. cos(x)/x

For NaN instances like these, I included a simple `try` check to substitute a denominator of 0 to a number as close to 0 as "pythonically" possible.

Are there any tips or tricks or built-in functions for these kinds of cases?

Comment: Hi! Is it intentional that [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html) is not on your tag list?

Comment: No. Why? Forgive my ignorance as I barely use numpy, how can it help?

Comment: Do you want it to notify that a `ZeroDivisionError` will occur? Or if it would occur, then fix a value before calculating?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html    you can ignore error and use nan_to_num function too.

Comment: @StevenSummers yes, to fix a value before calculating if it would occur.

Comment: Do you have a preferred value? Cause you could just use `try/except` statement and then re-call the function with amended values.